# Spring-integration-jdbc StoredProcOutboundGateway with DSL

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Have anyone done spring-integration-jdbc StoredProcOutboundGateway configuration with DSL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Spring Integration Java DSL for JDBC. Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) on the matter.

As the workaround we really don't have choice unless use `StoredProcOutboundGateway` class from the generic `.handle()` EIP-method:

```
@Bean
public StoredProcExecutor storedProcExecutor() {
    StoredProcExecutor storedProcExecutor = new StoredProcExecutor(this.dataSource);
    storedProcExecutor.setStoredProcedureName("CREATE_USER_RETURN_ALL");
    storedProcExecutor.setIsFunction(true);
    ...
    return storedProcExecutor;
}

...

    StoredProcOutboundGateway storedProcOutboundGateway = new StoredProcOutboundGateway(storedProcExecutor());
    storedProcOutboundGateway.setExpectSingleResult(true);
    storedProcOutboundGateway.setRequiresReply(true);

...

.handle(storedProcOutboundGateway)
```

Comment: Thanks @Arthem, for swift response, do we have a sample code where all the aspect of StoredProcOutboundGateway in java code rather xml configuration. I got an use case where the name to stored procedure and parameter will part of message header and I'm looking to leverage SpEL. Can this be done via java code (not XML). Do we have any reference or unit test code ?

Comment: Well, yeah... unfortunately there is no. However that should be clear that everything here is up to the `StoredProcExecutor`. See its JavaDocs for more info. If you need `setStoredProcedureNameExpression(Expression)`, you should to take a look into the `SpelExpressionParser`: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions. For parameters from message you should use `setProcedureParameters(List<ProcedureParameter>)` and use its `expression`. Please, raise a JIRA on the matter to add sample to Docs: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT

Comment: Thanks @Arthem, Your guidance helped. Following the doc reference you provide. now I have jdbc components with IntegrationFlow working like charm.

Comment: also see https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4529 for the related Jira issue